# PHP exploding by newline isn't working at all

Tags: php

Assuming that `$text = ea\r\ndad\r\n\r\nedade`

My first code:

```
$text = explode("\r\n",$text);
```

My new code

```
function splitNewLine($text) {
    $code=preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$text)));
    return explode("\n",$code);
}
$text = splitNewLine($text);
```

In both situations, `$text` ends up like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ea\r\ndad\r\n\r\nedade
)
```

And I really can't figure why... This is about it, no more code missing and yet it won't work. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: `preg_split('/\r?\n/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Nope, same. This is odd AF

Comment: Show us the code that you are using then. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e013edc2b051715b03fa60b8ebc2fb108d787b63

Comment: Probably you have ``$text = 'ea\r\ndad\r\n\r\nedade'``. So ``\n`` is not actually a line break.

Comment: Even the explode solution just works, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a09631e4f98b0dddfee6bc675ac30e49662dbf4d so my guess is that something else is going wrong. Note that "\n" is different from '\n' so maybe that is something to look for?

Comment: @AlexanderM. That seems to be about it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: As @AlexanderM. pointed out, [" " and ' ' are different in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @Fane you're welcome :)

Comment: @AlexanderM. Hi again alexander, sorry to bother you but would you mind checking this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107677/how-to-make-sure-string-has-double-quotes?noredirect=1# It is related to this one and I was hoping you could help me... tyvm :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use  **PHP_EOL**

```
$temp = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

OR

```
$temp = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $text);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: `PHP_EOL` depends on the platform. If the data comes from other places then it may not work as intended.