# How to make sure string has double quotes?

Tags: php

Firstly which of these functions return a string with **single quote:**

```
$data = strval($data);     
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$data);
```

And how can I assure my string has double quotes and both ends instead of `'` ? Tyvm for your help

EDIT: I receive my string directly in a POST (as in $received = $_POST["string"]) and run $received through one of those functions above that ultimately turns it into '$received' since it does not react to explode("\n",$received)

Comment: I sense a XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: A string does not have single or double quotes by default. They are only there if you add them to the string. Maybe it would help if you would clearly state what you are planning to do.

Comment: @Federico updated question

Comment: @maxhb updated question

Comment: I think you are overthinking, string is just string. single or double quote is made by us

Comment: @Andrew Wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php and I'm sure my problem is exactly this difference

Comment: I know the difference, but it is who we determine the single or double quote

Comment: @Andrew ... so? If it is *we who* determine the single or double quote how exactly can I guarantee my string has a double quote? Read the question carefully

Comment: i don't know what you're trying to do but why not use `$str = str_replace('\'', '"', $str)` to ensure that all single quotes are replaced by a double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's just the matter of how you declare your strings in the code.

All these functions (well, actually all functions that return a string) return just a string. Single quote/double quote matters when you specify the string right in the code.

```
echo '\nHey!'; // outputs `\nHey!`
echo "\nHey!"; //Outputs a blank line and `Hey!`
```

**So, double/single quote matters only when you specify those strings in the code.**

```
trim('\nHey!') // returns `\nHey!`
trim("\nHey!") // returns just `Hey!`
```

So, if you have some string in, let's say, `$_POST['str']`, it would be the exact same thing the user typed in the text field. If he put a newline there, it would be a newline, if he typed `\n`, it would be `\n`.

You can read more about single/double quote difference [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php?lq=1), but the only thing that you should keep in mind:

> That only matters for strings **YOU** declare **RIGHT IN THE CODE**

PHP might sometimes a seem a bit weird language, but it's absolutely sane (except for needle-haystack order :))

Good luck with PHP,

Best regards, Alexander.